# How to get table content on display after submit

Tags: html, forms, html-table, output, display

I'm just begin to study HTML for school.
Now I have to build a simple website with a form.

I did it in table-format.
The problem is that I need to show the input of the table on my display after using the submit-button.

I searched over 4 hours but did not find any solution.

Can someone help me with it?

Below my html-code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Salsa</title>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body>
  <h1>Salsa Events</h1>
  <p>Submit for your newsletter.<br>
  </p>

<form action="" method="get">

<center><table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td>First name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="first name" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Family name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="family name" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-mail</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="e-mail" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date of birth</td>
    <td><input type="date" name="date of birth" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Recieve newsletter</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="is_checkbox" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Send"> </td>
  </tr>
</table></center>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by default u want to hide the inputs and when click on send button u want to display all input ? right?

Comment: is there any backend method or just html

Comment: Yes, as soon as i click the send button the input disappears and a small kind of pupop must come with details (or a message that the newsletter is confrmed). There is no backend method and only a HTML.